# Set Theory - Prove that there is a function $f:\omega\to X$ such that $f(n)<f(n+)$ when $X$ has no maximal element.

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Suppose that $X$ is non-empty strictly ordered set, and that $X$ has no maximal element in a sense that for every $x\in X$ there exist $y\in X$ such that $x<y$. By using AC, show that there exists a function from $\omega$ to $ X$ such that $f(n)<f(n^{+})$ for all $n\in \omega$:

I think it's intuitively clear that such function exist. Since $X$ is non-empty we can pick an element $x_0\in X$. Then maximality condition asserts that there exist $x_1$ such that $x_0<x_1$, and iteratively we can find $x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots$. So (informally?) defining $f(n)=x_n$ will do.

However, I do not see why above argument requires axiom of choice. What part of it invokes AC/or what part of it is not rigourosly correct?

Comment: When you write "(informally?)": there you are using the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @Crostul Can you elarborate on how exactly am I using AC? Which non-empty disjoint sets from am I picking $x_k$ from?

Comment: At every induction step you are picking some $x_{k+1}$ from the nonempty set $\{ x: x > x_k\}$. Since you are doing this infinitely many times, you are using AC.

Comment: @Crostul I find that slightly misleading, because in many cases, we actually don't need any form of choice for this construction to go through. It's just the case that it might fail for some cases, if we don't assume a weak form of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify my answer, let us assume that $\operatorname{ZF}$ is consistent.

The axiom of **dependent choice** (DC) is the following statement:

Whenever $X$ is a nonempty set and $\prec \subseteq X \times X$ is a relation such that for all $x \in X$ there is some $y \in X$ with $x \prec y$, then there is a function $f \colon \omega \to X$ such that for all $n < \omega \colon f(n) \prec f(n+1)$.

It's an easy exercise to prove that $\operatorname{ZFC}$ proves $DC$. On the other hand, one can show that $\operatorname{ZF}$ doesn't prove $DC$ and also that $\operatorname{ZF + DC}$ doesn't prove the axiom of choice. Thus $DC$ can be regarded as "a weak form of choice".

Instead of only considering total orders, I want to allow partial orders as well.

Let $(X, \prec)$ be a strict (partial) order without maximal element. Then $\prec \subseteq X \times X$ satisfies the requirements of $(DC)$. Thus, if $DC$ is true, there is a function $f \colon \omega \to X$ such that $f(n) \prec f(n+1)$ for all $n < \omega$.

I claim that $DC$ is necessary in order to obtain this result in general: Suppose that $DC$ fails. Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $\prec \subseteq X \times X$ be a relation such that for all $x \in X$ there is some $y \in X$ with $x \prec y$, but there is no function $f \colon \omega \to X$ with $f(n) \prec f(n+1)$ for all $n < \omega$. Let $Y$ be the set of all functions $g \colon k \to X$ such that $k < \omega$ and $g(n) \prec g(n+1)$ for all $n+1 < k$. Then $(Y, \subsetneq)$ is a strict partial partial order without maximal element. By our assumption there is a function $h \colon \omega \to Y$ such that $h(n) \subsetneq h(n+1)$ for all $n < \omega$. Let $x_n$ be the last element of $h(n)$. So if $h(n) \colon k \to X$, then $x_n = h(n)(k-1)$. Now $f \colon \omega \to X, n \mapsto x_n$ satisfies $f(n) \prec f(n+1)$ for all $n < \omega$ - contradicting our choice of $(X, \prec)$.

Therefore the assumption that every strict partial order $(X, \prec)$ without maximal element admits a function $f \colon \omega \to X$ with $f(n) \prec f(n+1)$ for all $n < \omega$ implies the axiom of dependent choice.

Answer (score 0):

(1). A binary relation on $S$ is any subset of $S\times S.$ When $B\subset S\times S$ then dom$(B)=\{x\in S:\exists y\; ((x,y)\in B\}.$ The Axiom of Dependent Choice,which is a corollary of the Axiom of Choice,is : When $B$ is a binary relation on $S$ with dom$(B)=S,$ and $x\in S,$ there exists a function $f:\omega\to S$ with $f(0)=x$ and $\forall n\in \omega\; (f(n),f(n+1))\in B).$

Applying this with $X=S$ and with $(x,y)\in B\iff x<y$ gives the answer immediately, since $<$ is transitive.

(2). There are so many statements that have been shown to be equivalent to AC that different authors choose different versions. Kunen,in "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs", uses "Every set can be well-ordered."

Suppose $<_W$ is a well-order on $X.$ Let $x_0=\min_{<_W}X$ and let $x_{n+1}=\min_{<_W}\{y:x_n<_Wy\}.$ Note that although this uses recursion, and recursion does not require AC,  we cannot define the recursion  without $<_W,$ and we need AC to get $<_W .$